# Why didn't the complement's formula work?

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, formula, twos-complement, ones-complement

I have just learnt that to get the formula to find the 1st Complement is

```
    -x = 2^n - x - 1
```

I have managed to apply it on a binary case:

```
     -00001100 (base 2) = 2^8 - 12 - 1 
                        = 243
                        = 11110011 (1s)
```

However, when I try to apply the same formula to a base 5 number,

```
     -1042 (base 4) = 5^4 - 1042 - 1
                    = 625 - 1042 - 1
                    = - 400 (which is not the answer)
```

Can some one help me out here? Thanks

Comment: You are using '1042' as both a decimal and a pental number, for one thing

Comment: Somewhere in a parallel universe ... I have just learnt that right triangles satisfy `a^2 + b^2 = c^2`. However, when I try to apply the same formula to cubes, `a^3 + b^3 = c^3`, it does not hold for a = 3, b = 4, c = 5. Can someone help me out there?

Comment: 625 - 10**42** - 1 = -418,   
625 - 10**24** - 1 = -400

Comment: `(base 4) = 5^4` - decide on a base to use. Try doing manipulations using that representation.

Comment: @EmmadKareem It is not a new qustion, it is a joke. Look at my answer.

Comment: @BartoszMarcinkowski, Got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot calculate any formula with numbers in 2 different bases, you have to use their decimal representation (or an other representation you can handle)

I'll give it a try in dec:

```
1042 (base 5) = 1* 5^3 + 4* 5^1 + 2 = 125 + 20 + 2 = 147 dec
5^4 - 147 - 1 = 477 dec
477 = 3* 5^3 + 4* 5^2 + 2 = 3402 (base 5)
```

in base 5:

```
5^4 - 1042 - 1 = 10000 - 1043 = 3402
```

Comment: Your calculations are correct, but how are they related to ones' complement? Do you know a definition of ones' complement for base 5?

Comment: @BartoszMarcinkowski There is no 1's complement in base 5. IMO this can be called 4's compliment. I never used base 5 numbers before, but I know the 10's complement in base 10 (which is the pendant to the 2's complement in binary).