# Convert decimal to Two's complement hexadecimal

Tags: binary, hex, decimal, twos-complement

I am trying to figure out how to convert decimal to two's complement hexadecimal.

I completely understand how to take a decimal and find the two's complement of it (for both positive and negative values).

I also completely understand how Hexadecimal works for unsigned ints.

However, I am not sure how the two's complement rule can be used with hexadecimal. Is there a procedure to use Two's complement with hexadecimal?

Or is the procedure this: Convert decimal to two's compliment binary, then convert that to Hex. Is this the only thing that I would have to do? Or is there a more complex formula for find a twos complement hexadecimal number given a decimal number?

Thanks!

Edit: My latter thoughts were correct. I was supposed to convert the decimal number to two's compliment binary, then convert that binary to Hex. This is a very simple procedure.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/28117444/3684343 . It is about base 5 1's complement, but it is similar. Let me know if it helps, otherwise I can write an answer.

Comment: This was a big help! I think I understand now, thank you!